# Did I offend my prospective PhD supervisor?

Tags: phd

So I had cold emailed to a professor asking for a PhD position. Initially she did not have any but opened one for me. After several rounds of interviews I received an email from her offering phd position in her group. Later she informed me about her preferred start date and that is December. However since I’m an international student, I asked if it could be postponed by one month and if I start a month later.To which she didn’t reply. I also have email tracker. She has seen it but no reply. I have sent a follow up email but again no reply. Did I somehow offend her? What could be the reason?

Comment: How long after the first e-mail did you send the reminder (follow-up email)?

Comment: I suggest that you reconsider your use of email trackers. If I found one in an email I received, I would question whether I should continue to engage with the person who sent it.

Comment: Note that modern email software can test and block email trackers, and it is likely the recipient is aware of the tracker you inserted.

Comment: Hi. This is not the first time I have used the tracker during  communication also I have the advanced version of the tracker and the recipient wont be able to get the notification

Comment: @XINDA: That's even worse. At a base ethical level, you're being sneaky and trying to get the recipient's computer to tell you things about them that they have not actively or intentionally-passively told you themselves. At a technical level your "advanced version of the tracker" is either more visible than you think, or is exploiting a security vulnerability in their system.

Comment: @RLH Yeah Okay I do understand your point. But why all of a sudden? I have sent multiple emails to her over the period of 3 months. Nothing happened. Even when I confirmed that I accept the offer and that day only she replied and then within a hour I asked if I can start a month later and got no reply. I agree that using a tracker is ethically worse but I feel using the tracker is right or not, is the issue here.

Comment: "_I asked if it could be postponed by one month_" Did you tell her the reasons ? If you did, are they valid ? For example, if it is because of visa, did you tell her what's the average time of processing visa ? Also, please do not use e-mail tracker. It's intrusion of privacy. Whether she receive/open the e-mail is her privacy. Once you use the tracker, the professor would probably think you will continue to use it after you become her student. No one wants such a student.

Comment: "_why all of a sudden?_" Maybe she did not know about the tracker until the recent e-mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, asking for a later start shouldn't be offensive. An email tracker might be, though, if visible to the recipient.

You don't say how long it has been, but if it is less than, perhaps, two weeks, it is too soon to conclude anything. An repeated emails might be an issue if they follow on too quickly or are, themselves, imply impatience.

I suggest patience. And a bit of trust.

Be aware that a later start might cause problems and so might also cause a delay in decision making if things need to be arranged.

Comment: Hi, Yes I do understand. so basically last week I got the offer. So usually she replies quickly. So she suggested starting in December and asked if it was okay with me or not. but considering few complications at my end (my current job) so asked if it is okay with her if I request if I start in January. I have received no reply yet even after follow up email. Its highly unlikely that she is aware of the email tracker all of a sudden when I am using it from day 1 with her ( from June).

Comment: Whatever it is, Atleast she could let me know if the date is okay with her or not or she needs more time to think about it, if at all things need to be arranged

Comment: @XINDA keep in mind that this decision is very important to you, but probably only one of many important matters the professor is dealing with. They may be traveling, or given the time of year, they may be preparing for the start of the academic year. Demanding follow up after only one week is being impatient. As Buffy suggests a little patience may serve you well (and stop using email trackers).

Comment: Yeah thanks for the words! I was freaking out thinking I might have said something (reasons for asking for a one month delay in the date of joining. Ex visa and other stuff) which has offended her